# Imacros get downloaded image file name in firefox

Tags: imacros

I am using imacros in firefox and saving some images and I want to be able to store the saved images names in a variable, but it seems that the code at the end of my code below

```
SET !EXTRACT {{!DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME}}
PROMPT {{!DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME}}
```

does not work in firefox, only in ie, does anyone no how I can save the filename of the image into a variable for latter use in my imacros script in firefox browser, I prefer not to use ie browser if at all possible

thanks

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0
SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.somerandomsite.com
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://*.jpg

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Users\pb\Pictures\produts  FILE=* WAIT=YES  
'Download the picture
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM

TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:iv_thumb_image&&TXT:
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Users\pb\Pictures\produts  FILE=* WAIT=YES  
'Download the picture
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
SET !EXTRACT {{!DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME}}
PROMPT {{!DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME}}
```

Comment: You can save the filename of a jpg-image by adding the following code after your SAVEITEM-events:  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://*.jpg EXTRACT=HREF`  `SET DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/http:.*\/(.*\.jpg)/)[1]")`

Comment: thanks shugar, you should have made this a answer as it sloves my problem, thanks for helping, again...